# Innodb - Running an INSERT INTO SELECT - do records not show up until the whole thing is done?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a table of 26 million records, and wanted to add some columns to it, so I made a new table with the added columns then did a 
    `INSERT INTO table_new SELECT (field1,field2) FROM table_old`

I'm told this is quicker than trying to add columns to the existing table.

In any case, with 26 million records, this has taken a long time, and monitoring the process with MySQL Workbench, I see the process still running (40 hours and counting).

However, when I do a `SELECT * FROM table_new`, I don't see any records yet. With InnoDB, does it wait until the entire transaction is complete before I see any of the 26 million records in the new table? Or should I see the records inserted one-by-one in real time?

I'm looking at the status variable `Innodb_rows_inserted`, which previously was counting up steadily yesterday, and I think should represent my progress from 0 to 26-million, but now it is stationary at 14-million and not increasing in real time anymore :S, yet my `INSERT INTO SELECT` process is still running. I'm worried something's wrong.

How can I check that everything is working as expected?

Comment: Any self-respecting DBMS will make sure that the effects of a transaction that is not yet committed cannot be seen by other transactions. By incoporating InnoDB, MySQL finally joined that club of DBMSes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to keep track of the progress of a large commit *while it runs*, you could run your INSERT as a procedure.

This adds a little overhead, but you can then add a commit point after every x records (eg in the example below, commit after every 100 records)

NB This is written with Oracle in mind, so your mileage may vary, but hopefully you'll be able to translate to suit your needs.

```
declare
    v_counter       NUMBER := 0;
    cursor c_table_old is
        select *
        from table_old;
begin

    FOR l_table_old in c_table_old LOOP
        insert into table_new (field1, field2) 
        values (l_table_old.field1,
                l_table_old.field2);

        v_counter := v_counter + 1;

        IF (MOD(v_counter, 100) = 0) THEN
            commit;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;

end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea for *future* attempts.

But so I guess it's true that with InnoDB, it waits until the entire transaction is complete before I see any of the 26 million records in the new table?

However, since I'm not seeing any more `innodb_rows_inserted` being incremented, I'm worried the whole thing failed somehow, yet the process is still alive and I cannot check if there is progress. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's an answer from DBA StackExchange in relation to a similar issue on InnoDB, looks like it could be useful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/internal-reason-for-killing-process-taking-up-long-time-in-mysql